# customized function raw query in Laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, performance, function, laravel-4

Please indicate me where i can add a customized function in Laravel framework or is there something missing in the installation?
i'm trying to use the function

```
public function select($query, $bindings = array())
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function($me, $query, $bindings)
    {
        if ($me->pretending()) return array();

        // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
        // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
        // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
        $statement = $me->getPdo()->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute($me->prepareBindings($bindings));

        return $statement->fetchAll($me->getFetchMode());
    });
}
```

from the tutorial http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries
but i cannot find where to modify my existing Laravel framework.

I need to run a query have inner join from 3 tables and collect the data and post it in grid. I need to modify in Laravel framework and create a function of my own.

Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: ok so explain exactly what you want to do ?
I don't see why you need to create a function of your own ?
What can't you do with the query builder ?

Comment: Do U mean with the query builder i can fed in any query and call the query to run and get the data from desired database?

Comment: This is the example of laravel documentation.
With that start you can do what you want.$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();

Comment: Please can i pass a query like this 
SELECT *, tarifhotelprix.marque AS prixmarque   
FROM $tablename 
INNER JOIN tarifhotel ON tarifhotel.idtarifhotel = $tablename.tarifhotel_idtarifhotel 
INNER JOIN typedetarif ON typedetarif.idtypedetarif  = $tablename.typedetarif_idtypedetarif  
INNER JOIN typedechambre ON typedechambre.idtypedechambre= $tablename.typedechambre_idtypedechambre  
INNER JOIN brochurehotel ON brochurehotel.idbrochurehotel= $tablename.brochurehotel_idbrochurehotel 
WHERE tarifhotel.idtarifhotel = '$idtarifhotel' 
AND  brochurehotel.idbrochurehotel = '$idbrochure'

Comment: yes you can forget the query builder of course and just pass the string as you wrote just use that :
DB::raw('sql expression here');

Comment: Thank u for the response but where can i place it in the framework structure ? Should i call it from C:\wamp\www\laravel-master\app\controllers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes so in your controllers you have method that correspond to a route.
So choose the method corresponding to your route and call this function in that method.

For example in your HomeController.php

```
Class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $yourData = DB::raw('your query');
        // if you want to inject it in your view.
        return View::make('yourtemplatename', ['yourdata' => $yourData]);
    }
}
```

And in your file routes.php

```
route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

But there is prettiest way to do queries with Eloquent.
Check the documentation for that.Your query is not as hard as it looks it a forest of join.

Comment: Thank U, should it necessarily be in function index() 
as i already have  public function index()
 {
  // get all the nerds
  $nerds = Nerd::all();

  // load the view and pass the nerds
  return View::make('nerds.index')
   ->with('nerds', $nerds);
 }